# Collections.sort() Fails In large ArrayList, Frequently sorted

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I've seen a lot of posts related to this issue but every desk check I've performed and suggestion I've implemented did not help. I can't figure out how I am violating the contract of the comparator. Granted I don't use comparators that often.

I have a large ArrayList of objects that are sorted on every update because their positions frequently change. I have to render these objects form bottom-left to top-right order to preserve a 'depth' like look to a 2D program.

Here is my comparator:

```
@Override
public int compare(RenderObject o1, RenderObject o2) 
{
    //if(o1 == null || o2 == null)
    //    return 0;

    if(o1 == null)
        return -1;
    else if(o2 == null)
        return 1;

    //vertices in order top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left
    PointF[]    bounds1 = o1.getVertices(),
                bounds2 = o2.getVertices();

    //if(bounds1 == null || bounds2 == null || bounds1.equals(bounds2))
    //  return 0;

    if(bounds1 == null)
        return -1;
    else if(bounds2 == null)
        return 1;

    if(bounds1[0].x >= bounds2[1].x || bounds1[3].y <= bounds2[0].y)
        return 1;
    else if(bounds1[1].x <= bounds2[0].x || bounds1[0].y >= bounds2[3].y)
        return -1;

    return o1.getZOrder() < o2.getZOrder() ? 1 : (o1.getZOrder() > o2.getZOrder() ? -1 : 0);
}
```

Can someone please explain where the contract is violated. I tried desk checking with the same exact vertices for both o1 & o2 and couldn't figure out how they are not equal. If it can't be helped I suppose I'll have to implement sorting manually, it would probably be more efficient since not all objects will move every update, but I would still like to fix this code, if for nothing else future reference.

EDIT: Here is the actual error, but it's right where all other's stop with this issue.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeForceCollapse(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
at ....Map.update(Map.java:237)
at ....GameMain.update(GameMain.java:76)
at ....BasicGame.start(BasicGame.java:173)
at ....GameMain.main(GameMain.java:121)
```

Comment: If you cannot figure it out, as a stopgap measure you can turn off this consistency check with some system property.

Comment: Thank you Thilo, that may be useful to remember in the future as I honestly wanted to ignore this and let my rendering guy handle this!

Comment: By the way, I really like how much detail you put into your question, making it both clear as well as giving us information about what you've tried and where you're at. You're just the type of Stack Overflow contributor we're looking for.  I've tweeted this question to my followers, as I hope it helps others with the same problem.

Comment: Thanks @jmort253 I appreciate that. I always try to remember to turn my verbose setting on when posting on SO ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have to deal with `null`? Because that could be a problem.

Right now, you return "equal" when `null` is involved.

So   1 < 2,  and 1 == null,  so null should be smaller than 2, but it is also equal here.

To fix it, either error out on `null` (if that is an option, you'd need to avoid null values), or make `null` the smallest.

```
if (a == b) return 0;
if (a == null) return -1;
if (b == null) return 1;
```

---

Also if you do `>=` you cannot return `1` or `-1`. It could be equal, right? In particular, comparing an object to itself (or a clone of itself) must return `0`. This seems like a good case for unit testing.

Comment: Oh, I get it now.  Awesome answer. +1  Basically, you're saying that null's position in the ordering is ambiguous.

Comment: That's one thing for sure - presume three `RenderObject`; `a`, `b` and `null`, where `a < b`, then `compare(null,a) == 0`, but `compare(null,b) != compare(a,b)`

Comment: Definitely a great observation, I edited my post & code to reflect, but it sadly is still crashing. Oh and to answer your question, there is a possibility that objects may be null for 1 tick before removed automatically by the map.

Comment: You still need to return 0, when both are null. But maybe the problem is the non-null case. There is a lot of `||`. that can probably also go both ways and become inconsistent.

Comment: Also if you do `>=` you cannot return `1` or `-1`. It could be equal, right? This seems like a good case for unit testing.

Comment: Yeah I thought so too, I compared for both null returning 0 didn't work. I put it all in a try/catch and check what classes extending RenderObject exactly were the issue, then printed out their bounds. Turns out they are the same object and I wrote out the desk check this shouldn't be happening. I'll editwith more info.

Comment: It turns out the = part was indeed the issue. Kind of unfortunate because it was in there because physics corrections from collisions can result in a 1 pixel overlap for 1 tick (sometimes but rarely), which will probably result in some annoying flashing. Never-the-less I can at least now continue working on the project without it crashing! Thank you so very much! ^_^

Comment: I want to echo what Thilo says about unit testing. It's helped me immensely in cases where I have a small function that takes various inputs and gives various outputs. Unit testing ensures you can tweak the code while giving you real time feedback about all of the different inputs for which the outputs will not be correct and vice versa.